# Script to check if there are other scripts

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

When archiving web pages, dynamic content has to be treated differently.
How do I detect whether a page uses any JavaScript?

This will end up in a browser extension, so it probably doesn't need to exclude itself from the findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply checking for `<script>` tags should be fine.

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("script").length) {
    //there are scripts on this page
}
```

You *could* scan the entire page for `onclick`, etc handlers in HTML tags, but that would be slow for a big page.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually relatively simple -- does it have any `<script>` tags? Then it probably has dynamic content. Additionally, you may wish to check for `<object>` tags as occasionally embedded objects will modify the page as well (though I suppose their presence should also make the page considered 'dynamic')

Answer (score -1):

With javascript it ain't possible if javascript is turned off in your browser. You must make some browser check in your server-code.